# Syntax Error in Insert to statement for Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

I need help with my coding, I have tried changing variables and displaying the SQL and I still can not see the error

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
qryCustomerInformation.SQL.Add('/*The SQL query string from below*/');
showmessage(qryCustomerInformation.SQL.Text);
qryCustomerInformation.ExecSQL;
```

Here is my query string:

```
INSERT INTO BasicInformation (
    Passwords, 
    CustomerID, 
    Names, 
    Surname, 
    Age, 
    IdentitiyNumber, 
    Address, 
    CardNumber, 
    CSV, 
    Expirey, 
    Image, 
    PhoneNumber
) VALUES (
    ''' + CustomerPassword + 
    ''',''' + CustomerId + 
    ''',''' + CustomerName + 
    ''',''' + CustomerSurname + 
    ''',''' + CustomerAge + 
    ''',''' + CustomerIdNumber + 
    ''',''' + CustomerAddress + 
    ''',''' + CustomerCardNumber + 
    ''',''' + CustomerCSV + 
    ''',''' + CustomerExpirey + 
    ''',''' + CustomerImage + 
    ''',''' + CurstomerPhoneNumber 
+ ''')
```

Comment: A screenshot like the one you have provided is absolutely no use for getting help here.  Please copy/paste the text of your Sql into into your question.  Meanwhile, -1

Comment: If any of the variables have a single quotation mark in them, you're going to retrieve a syntax error if you have not escaped the variables and it will break your query string. Due to the fact that you've provided very little information on this, it is hard to tell what your issue is.

Comment: Gah. Use parameters. Avoid quoting issues and defend from SQL injection.

Comment: Using parameters also makes dealing with date/time types much easier. Be lazy, make your own life easier, use params. That's what they are there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the reason that you are having problems is that your SQL is syntactically
unnecessarily complicated.  Assuming `CustomerPassword`, etc are all string variables,
you can simplify your Sql as follows:

```
var InsertSql : String;

begin
  [...]
  InsertSql :=
  'INSERT INTO BasicInformation ('
   + '    Passwords, '
   + '    CustomerID, '
   + '    Names, '
   + '    Surname, '
   + '    Age, '
   + '    IdentitiyNumber, '
   + '    Address, '
   + '    CardNumber, '
   + '    CSV, '
   + '    Expirey, '
   + '    Image, '
   + '    PhoneNumber'
   + ')'
   + ' VALUES ('
   + QuotedStr(CustomerPassword) + ', '
   [... etc]
   + QuotedStr(CurstomerPhoneNumber) + ')'
   ;

   qryCustomerInformation.SQL.Add(InsertSql);
```

I have added the InsertSql local variable to avoid constructing the Sql within
the call to qryCustomerInformation.SQL.Add(), because that frequently results in errors itself.

The code above uses `QuotedStr` around the values of the string variables.  It not only supplies the necessaryu surrounding quotes but also correctl handles the case where the variable's value includes embedded single-quote marks.

However, as David Heffernan says, it is better to use a parameterised query,
for which you need to add a parameter to qryCustomerInformation for each value
in the `Values` clause, and modify the InsertSql so that it refers to each of them
instead of the original string value, like so

```
   + ' VALUES ('
   + ':CustomerPassword, '
   etc.
```

`qryCustomerInformation` will automatically substitute the parameter values for the labels prceded by colons.

Btw, your code contains a number of spellings which look suspicious to me:
Expir**e**y
CustomerExpir**e**y
Cu**r**stomerPhoneNumber

Comment: Martyn Although I also strongly agree that he should switch to parameters to prevent SQL injections, in your first solution you are forgetting to quote the values. You should replace CustomerPassword by QuotedStr(CustomerPassword), and repeat that for every other value.

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks very much for spotting @MarcGuillot!